# Xamarin - trying to create a equivalent of JS setInterval using Thread

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I was creating a puzzle with a bit of information in different sources to create this...

```
System.Threading.Thread th;
th = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
{
    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        lbMemFree.Text = "memory free: " + NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.PhysicalMemory; // this works!
    });
}));
th.Start();
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    th.Sleep(500); // delay execution for 500 ms
    // more code
});
```

The idea is to create something that update the label times in time. In this scenario: 500ms.

But the `th.Sleep(500)` don't allow the app to compile. It's says:  Error CS0176: Static member `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int)` cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead (CS0176).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use async await for this.

**Interval**

```cs
public class Interval
{
    public static async Task SetIntervalAsync(Action action, int delay, CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(delay, token);
                action();
            }
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException) { }           
    }
}
```

**usage (e.g. Console Application for demo)**

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Interval.SetIntervalAsync(DoSomething, 1000, cts.Token);

        Console.ReadKey(); // cancel after first key press.
        cts.Cancel();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Use the `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel the execution of the interval.

Comment: Sorry..this will not work..because it's static...Looks like you can't update UI elements into static calls.

Comment: Nevermind...it's easy...If I drop the static declaration..works like a charm ;) ty !

Comment: @MarcoJr The method isn't using any instance members, so it has no reason to not be `static`.